# Angular 2: pipe not working in nested component

Tags: angular

My custom pipes worked until I made my ngFor list it's own component.

This works:

```
<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let item of items | myPipe : 'someString'">
    {{item}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Pipe doesn't work after I make the ul it's own component:

```
<div>
  // ul is now in it's own component
  <app-items-list [items]="items"></app-item>
</div>
```

The app-items-list component works fine if I don't try to use myPipe, but using myPipe in the nested component throws this error:

```
zone.js:516 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 
The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Pipe for a particular item not for all the value in the list. And in unorderedlist you can't use pipes just you can use pipes for a list.For Example see the below code

```
<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li>{{item | myPipe : 'someString'}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It does work just fine in an unordered list. The problem is that it stops working when I move the list into it's own component.

Comment: Why can't you use                                                                                 <app-items-list ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items"></ app-items-list>   (or)                           <app-items-list *ngFor="let item of items | myPipe : 'someString'"></app-items-list>